# Unit test serializer Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django and I want to test my CRUD for Approval class that I did but I encountered error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Django_Workspace\berryenroll\BerryEnroll\api\tests.py", line 19, in test_add
    serializer.create(validated_data)
  File "E:\Django_Workspace\berryenroll\BerryEnroll\api\serializers.py", line 29, in create
    validated_data['username'] = self.context['request'].user.username
KeyError: 'request'

this is the test class:

```
class ApprovalTest(TestCase):
    def test_add(self):

        validated_data = dict()
        validated_data['status'] = 'APPROVED'
        validated_data['given_role'] = ['ROLE_ADMIN']
        validated_data['asked_role'] = ['ROLE_ADMIN']
        serializer = ApprovalRequestSerializer(data=validated_data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print(serializer.data)
            serializer.create(validated_data)
        else:
            print(serializer.errors)
```

This is the Approval model with customUser:

```
matrix_roles = settings.MATRIX_RULES
allowed_roles = list(set([elem.role for elem in matrix_roles])) # Convert to a unique list


LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted([(item, item) for item in get_all_styles()])
STATUS_CHOICES = sorted([(item, item) for item in ["PENDING", "APPROVED", "REJECTED", "CANCELED"]])
ROLE_CHOICES = sorted([(item, item) for item in allowed_roles])

class ApprovalRequest(models.Model):
    # TODO: Add caller_id ?
    username = models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='PENDING', max_length=100)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='username')
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    asked_role = MultiSelectField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default=settings.ASKED_DEFAULT_ROLE, max_length=100)
    given_role = MultiSelectField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default=settings.ASKED_DEFAULT_ROLE, max_length=100)

    # given_role = models.CharField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default=settings.ASKED_DEFAULT_ROLE, max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']






class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), unique=True, max_length=255)

    roles = []
    objects = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def save (self, **kwargs):
        """saving to DB disabled"""
        pass


    def get_group_permissions (self):
        """If you don't make your own permissions module,
           the default also will use the DB. Throw it away"""
        return [] # likewise with the other permission defs

    def get_and_delete_messages (self):
        """Messages are stored in the DB. Darn!"""
        return []
```

And this is the ApprovalSerializer:

```
class ApprovalRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    given_role = fields.MultipleChoiceField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES,required=False)
    asked_role = fields.MultipleChoiceField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES,required=False)

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = ApprovalRequest
        read_only_fields = ['username', 'creation_date', 'created_by', 'last_update', 'updated_by']


    def create(self, validated_data):
        now = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

        """Override default dataform read-only fields"""
        validated_data['username'] = self.context['request'].user.username
        validated_data['status'] = 'PENDING'
        validated_data['created_by'] = self.context['request'].user.username
        validated_data['creation_date'] = now
        validated_data['updated_by'] = self.context['request'].user.username
        validated_data['last_update'] = now
        return super(ApprovalRequestSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        now = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        validated_data['updated_by'] = self.context['request'].user.username
        validated_data['last_update'] = now

        res = super(ApprovalRequestSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

        # Check if the new role is approved, the call the Gateway to update the user role
        if 'status' in validated_data.keys():
            if validated_data['status'] == 'APPROVED':
                logger.info("The role should be updated to %s" % list(validated_data['given_role']))
                server_url = settings.BCS_URL
                username = settings.BCS_ADMIN_USERNAME
                password = settings.BCS_ADMIN_PASSWORD
                bcs = System(server_url)
                bcs.login_as_admin(username, password)
                users = bcs.users()
                # Look for my user in the gateway and update it's 'authorities'
                for user in users:
                    if user['login'] == instance.username:
                        user['authorities'] = list(validated_data['given_role'])
                        bcs.update_user(user)
                        # TODO: Log warning if the user does not exist / This case should never happen / Synchro error with gateway
                # pass
        return res
```

I want just to test the create and update method but I don't know how to add context['request'] to test it

Answer (score 1):

you need to use DRF's RequestFactory, like so:

```
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory

class ApprovalTest(TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        # ...
        user = SomeUserFactory()
        request_factory = APIRequestFactory()
        request = request_factory.post('/')
        request.force_authenticate(user)
        serializer = ApprovalRequestSerializer(data=validated_data, context={"request": request})
```

please note that in some cases, the URL that you pass to request factory may be significant. Also, you may need to override the URL's used in test case - what I mean by that is that sometimes you have the main urls.py being used by the application and some other urls.py which correspond to the API (when you have two different workers serving the app and the API). You do that by setting `urls` classvar of the test case like so:

```
from django.test import override_settings

@override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF='my_app.urls')
class ApprovalTest(TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        # ....
```

however, because your serializer is relying on request and user, you could also consider writing a test for the view itself. The view would then call serializer under the hood and so you would be able to test the serializer via the view, like so:

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

class MyViewTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        user = SomeUserFactory()
        client = APIClient()

        # you can also use force_authenticate here to indicate that the user has
        # already been logged in or actually test what happens when you don't do this
        # presumabely the view should return a 401 or something similar.

        client.force_authenticate(user)

        # url could either be a path, e.g. /some-url/

        # url = "/some-api-endpoint/"

        # or you could use reverse, like so:

        # url = reverse('my-view-name', kwargs={ ... })

        response = client.post(url, data={"given_role": "something", "asked_role": "something-else"})

        # now you can check either the response code, like so:

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        # or you can check the content returned like so:

        self.assertEqual(response.json(), {"some": "expected", "json": "output"})
```

I hope this helps you somehow. I would also strongly encourage you to take a look at pytest and pytest-django. thanks to pytest fixture support, you can get rid of code replication very quickly. You can then also replace `self.assert*()` calls with `assert foo == bar` statements though it's a personal preference of course and has nothing to do with the essense of your problem.